# copy webpart page (aspx page) with web parts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a web part page "DocLib1.aspx" in document library "DobLib1" and it has few webparts.

How can I take the same web part page and copy it to other document libraries (there are about 50+ document libraries). The web part page is named after the document library (with aspx extension). One of the web part is the list for the same doc lib where the web part is residing.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me for SharePoint 2010:

1. Open the site in **SharePoint Designer 2010**
2. Right click the page and select copy.
3. Select a different folder
4. Rename the page
5. Move it back to the original folder.

All the WebParts will be intact.
This might seem elementary, but within SharePoint copying a page **doesn't** copy any of the WebPart on the page. That drove me bonkers.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do you get to the individual page in Designer 2010? When I click on the library all I see are the library properties.

Comment: @onafetsid You can find the individual pages in the Views and Forms box on the right of the property pages.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options to copy and paste a Sharepoint 2010 page and retain its web parts:

1. Perform the copy and paste through Sharepoint Designer 2010.
2. Access any page in Sharepoint Browser and go to Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure. Copy and paste is possible from here but copy and paste within the same directory can fail; paste in a different directory level then rename the file.

Comment: Manage Content and Structure worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this site when also looking for a solution to copying a webpart page, but I actually found an even easier way.  I've got a library that holds webpart pages, and whenever I need another page that is similar to one of the others in the library, I go to Library Tools > Library in the ribbon, and then Open with Explorer.  From there, I simply Copy/Paste the webpart page that is similar to what I want into the same library and then rename the page.  Then I can open the new page and make the needed changes.

Comment: this is the only solution which works also in case SPD is disallowed for the site or without the publishing feature

Comment: This method doesn't copy the web parts for me (using SP 2010).

Answer (score 0):

To add my experience to qhawk's solution (I cant just add a comment directly under the solution as I have less than 50 rep) - in SharePoint Designer 2010, I had to go to Site Objects --> All Files --> then select the relevant Library which has the page you want to copy, copy it to another Library, e.g. Shared Documents, rename it there, copy it back, job done.

I found that if I just selected Site Objects --> Lists and Libraries --> and chose my Library from there, it wouldnt list the actual items in the library to be able to copy them, not even in the Views or Forms box. You have to go through the 'All Files' route.

PS. I know this is an old thread, but I found this whilst trying to find the solution for this, and after finding qhawk's solution needed a little tweaking for me, thought I'd let others know incase someone else stumbles across this.